# Need a complete conference solution for LAN

Tags: windows, lan, conferencing

I'm looking for a software tool that does the following

Has:

- Contact list
- Group Text chat
- Group Video chat
- Group Chalkboard
- Group Presentation
- Group windows desktop viewing (and assistance)

All without an internet connection over LAN. But hopefully, with the ability to connect over the internet. Also for windows.

Anyone know of something like this? I don't mind if it needs a server or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle might be what you are looking for.

EDIT 10/15/2010: Since I am unable to post comments here is a follow up:

If you are looking for something similar to MSN messenger, then you may look at [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol). This is the same protocol that google talk uses and there are quite a few clients that support it.

Comment: Moodle is based on virtual learning on the web, I need a desktop client, smoething more like skype or msn, but using LAN instead, thanx

Comment: Thanks again, but i'm looking for a complete package solution